# MKMapView moves around screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I am using an MKMapView to create a thumbnail on my screen.  However it doesn't render in the position that I set it to on IB.  It moves up.  It also moves up even further after I go to push and pop a screen over it. Any idea how to position this correctly?

[image: Here it is in IB]

[image: running]

[image: after pop/push it moves higher]

Comment: also there was toolbar at the bottom after the push/pop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was related to auto sizing.

also there was toolbar at the bottom after the push/pop.